# Applying a custom SKShader to SKScene that pixelates the whole rendered scene in iOS 8 SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: ios, opengl-es, swift, sprite-kit, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create a full-screen pixelation effect on SKScene. I've learned that there should be two options to do this:

- Using a custom `SKShader` using GLES 2.0.
- Using Core Image filters.

I've tried to add a custom SKShader that should modify the whole screen by pixelating it. I'm not sure that if it's possible, but documentation from `SKScene` (which is a subclass of `SKEffectNode`) suggests it:

> An SKEffectNode object renders its children into a buffer and
>   optionally applies a Core Image filter to this rendered output.

It's possible to assign a SKShader to the SKScene, as in `GameScene : SKScene`:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "pixelation.fsh")
    self.shader = shader
    self.shouldEnableEffects = true
}
```

... but it seems that the rendered buffer is not passed as the u_texture to the GLES:

```
void main()
{
    vec2 coord = v_tex_coord;
    coord.x = floor(coord.x * 10.0) / 10.0;
    coord.y = floor(coord.y * 10.0) / 10.0;
    vec4 texture = texture2D(u_texture, coord);
    gl_FragColor = texture;
}
```

... so the previous shader doesn't work.

If I assign that shader to a texture-based `SKSpriteNode`, it works.

So is it possible to modify the whole frame buffer (and for example pixelate it) as a post-processing measure after all the nodes have been rendered?

**Edit**: I found a way to do the pixelation using Core Image filters in OS X ([How do you add a CIPixellate Core Image Filter to a Sprite Kit scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659725/how-do-you-add-a-cipixellate-core-image-filter-to-a-sprite-kit-scene/24659726?noredirect=1#comment40852930_24659726)), but copying that implementation doesn't yield any results on iOS. According to the [documents](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPixellate) `CIPixellate` should be `Available in OS X v10.4 and later and in iOS 6.0 and later.`.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work using Core Image filter `CIPixellate`. I used is as a filter to `SKEffectNode` to produce the pixelation effect. Couple of things to note:

- `SKScene` is a subclass of `SKEffectNode`, but applying the filter to `SKScene` doesn't work. It'll mess up the background and doesn't do any pixellation.
- You need to create a `SKEffectNode` and add the nodes to be pixelated under that.

Here's the solution based on the code generated when you choose a `Game` type project with `Swift`:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var effectNode : SKEffectNode = SKEffectNode.node()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(5.0, forKey: "inputScale")

        self.effectNode.filter = filter
        self.effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = true
        self.addChild(effectNode)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

            sprite.xScale = 0.5
            sprite.yScale = 0.5
            sprite.position = location

            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

            sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

            self.effectNode.addChild(sprite)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get your `.shader` running on `SKScene`, you need to set `shouldEnableEffects` to true on the scene (same thing goes for `SKEffectNode`).

While technically, that "works" (the shader is applied), there's a bug in the rendering of the scene afterwards that gets slightly resized.

So using `CoreImage` filters is, so far, the best way to go.

Comment: Yes, and I actually found out that if I use the `CoreImage` filter (see my answer below) directly on `SKScene`, it will somehow make the background transparent (black) and mess up the whole rendering - without creating the desired effect. I didn't have time to dig this further, may be a bug in SpriteKit. Anyway, adding a child (`SKEffectNode`) and a filter to that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do the exact same thing for a recent project as a way to transition between levels, and ended up doing a work around for it.  Basically, I took a screenshot of the screen in the code then when I loaded the next level, I called a previously saved screenshot of how the level should look when it was loaded.  I added the previous level screenshot as an SKSpriteNode and then ran the shader a number of times until it was incredibly pixelated.  Then I did the same to the screenshot for that level and replaced the two and then I un-pixelated the second screenshot so it looked like as soon as the level was beaten everything pixelated itself then un-pixelated itself to reveal a new level.

```
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
            self.view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            //UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            protoImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(CGImage: image.CGImage!))
            protoImage.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
            node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
            protoImage.zPosition = 9000
```

Second Scene

```
           let shader: SKShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "RWTGradient2.fsh")
           let ratioX: Float = divisor/Float(protoImage.frame.size.width)
           let ratioY: Float = divisor/Float(protoImage.frame.size.height)
           shader.uniforms = [

                SKUniform(name: "ratioX", float: ratioX),
                SKUniform(name: "ratioY", float: ratioY),

           ]
           protoImage.shader = shader;
```

Comment: Where do you get the shader("RWTGradient2.fsh") from? Or do you know any good places to learn how to create the shader?