# Why is a shader not applied on a SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, fragment-shader

As per the documentation, `SKScene` is a child of `SKEffectNode` and thus should conform and apply the shader property if not nil.

I've successfully added a shader to individual SKSprites (so I know my shader code is working) but if I apply that same shader to the Scene, nothing happens, no error, nothing.

I've tried initializing the shader at multiple places :

- in the init of the SKscene
- in the ControllerView that initializes the SKscene
- in sceneDidLoad of the SKscene
  to no avail.

Is there anything that I'm missing ?

(I'm using adapted code from https://github.com/twostraws/ShaderKit)

A similar question was asked 6 years ago ([Applying a custom SKShader to SKScene that pixelates the whole rendered scene in iOS 8 SpriteKit with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072230/applying-a-custom-skshader-to-skscene-that-pixelates-the-whole-rendered-scene-in)) but labels the quirk as a bug (Maybe it was just never corrected in the meantime ?)

Comment: Did you remember to set shouldEnableEffects?

Comment: I. Did. Not. Why is that not more proeminently written in the docs !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always remember to set `shouldEnableEffects` to `true`.